# Validate Identical / Duplicate Value on Kendo Grid Column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im Stuck Where I want to validate the Column for Shift Day and limit it to Unique Data , I have a DropDownlist for Days but i want to show a message when it is already in the Kendo Grid. .

This is my Kendo Grid

```
 $("#customerContactGrid").kendoGrid({
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/Client/LoadClientCustomerLocationContactList?clientCusLocId=' + clientCusLocId,
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }

            },
            pageSize: 10
        },
        rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#clientContactTemplate").html().replace('k-alt', '')),
        altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#clientContactTemplate").html())
    });
```

THIS IS MY DROPDOWN LIST

```
<span>
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlShiftDay", new SelectList(ViewBag.ShiftList, "ID", "Display_Value", clientCustomerShiftDay), "[Please Select]",
          new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"class","validate[required] inputLong"}
                })
            </span>
```

THIS IS MY CONTROLLER:

```
private void GetShiftList()
        {
            // get status list from lookups
            var shiftlist = (from a in db.Lookups
                             where a.Domain == "AVAILABLEDAY"
                             select a).ToList();
            // add status list to a data container be called in view
            ViewBag.ShiftList = shiftlist;
        }
```

Hope someone can Help me to Show a message that will prompt if the user entered data that is already Present in the Grid Column

Answer (score 1):

there are few things to understand in your problem

The kendo UI you are using is filled by ajax call

```
url: '/Client/LoadClientCustomerLocationContactList?clientCusLocId=' + clientCusLocId,
dataType: "json",
type: "POST"
```

which is in turn populated by a server side method.

Now the dropdown selection is a client side event which again fires a new AJAX call on the Server.

To compare the data you have two ways :

no.1 save result of previous ajax call on the server and compare the result on the next AJAX call on the server itself and return null if data is common

no.2 On receiving the result of the ajax call on dropdown event use client side script to do compare.

#### Update

something for method #2 might go like

```
$(".dayDropDown").change(function(){
        
           var str = $( this ).text();
           var tableData = $("#customerContactGrid").html();
           if(tableData.indexOf(str) != -1){  // find the day in table data
                    //True condition statements
           }else{
                    //False condition statements
           }
            
});
```

Comment: Sir there's something wrong with the one you give. . tabledata returns the whole HTML file for the Grid but not its values

Comment: the tableData here is string object of html markup of the table, it will include the markup and the data with in the markup.

Comment: Sir , i used that approach but it only returns the last value of my kendo grid

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to export a grid:

```
function ExportGrid(gridName, exportTitle, exportFormat) {

        showWaitIndicator(true);
        var grid = $('#' + gridName).data('kendoGrid');
        var exportGridRequest = {            
            title: exportTitle,
            columns: JSON.stringify(grid.columns),
            data:JSON.stringify(grid.dataSource.data().toJSON()),
            format:exportFormat
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("ExportCreate","Grid")',
            datatype: "json",
            traditional: true,
            data: exportGridRequest,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                showWaitIndicator(false);
                if (data.FileIdentifier != null) {

                    window.location.href='@Url.Action("DownloadFile")?fileIdentifier='+data.FileIdentifier;
               } else
                   alert(jqxhr.responseText);               
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                showWaitIndicator(false);
                result = false;
                var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                var err = msg.Message;
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

    }
```

The data property is not lightweight as it holds all data in the grid but unless you do some fancy searching you could get a grid instance:

```
var grid = $('#' + gridName).data('kendoGrid');
var columns= JSON.stringify(grid.columns);
var data=JSON.stringify(grid.dataSource.data().toJSON());
```

As far as I know your search would need to use the columns and the data (where grouping is tricky). There is probably a much faster way via looping all elements of a div client side.